# Scrapy weird output after crawling

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Im working on a new project and i try to crawl [link](https://www.karton.eu/einwellig-ab-100-mm)

**What i did**

First of all i tried to get some informations in my shell, to work things out correctly.
code i wrote in my shell: `response.xpath(//div[@class="product-wrapper col-xs-6 col-md-4"]/text()').get()`
With this code i just want to print out the title of the product, but i get some very weird output:

[image: see here]

my first problem was something with the robots.txt so i change my settings.py user agent and now it works, i guess we can determine that the error come from that change, right? correct me if im wrong.

After a bit of research i found out that this comes from wrong formatting and you can determine this error with something like that:
`response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="product-wrapper col-xs-6 col-md-4"]/text())')` but this didnt help me at all.

What can i do now?

Comment: Doesn't look like your xpath selectors are getting you the correct data. The outputs don't have anything meaningful in there. The normalize-space function works on start and end spacing, not \n\t specifically.

Comment: even if i try to crawl something like ```<div class="delivery-status">``` with ```response.xpath('//div[@class="delivery-status"]/text()').get()``` i get an output like in the picture above

Comment: Hey @AaronS what can i do if i have problems with finding the correct html-tags? the information is completely stored different, than in my project before. In my html-tool(Browser Key F12) i thought i found the tag, that contains all information from the page, like my productlink clearfix before, but i get always [] as output or something like that.. im kind of frustrated now..

Comment: I think anyone doing this type of scripts will come into contact with not getting the items they want as output. I think being mindful of where the html tag and class attribute sit in the HTML tree gives you a lot. I could tell straight away that you hadn't accessed the right text, because the div didn't contain text, it was the div/a/ that contained the text. Sometimes scrapy's response isn't the same the HTML and this depends entirely on the websitse make up, whether it has javascript involved etc..Or measures to stop scrapers from gaining information.

Comment: You should inspect the HTML tree in a browser to seek out where the text sits or where the attribute value is. I am forever inspecting the sites HTML when thinking about XPATH selectors.

Comment: I inspected them for 5 hours today..

Comment: So that's way too long, after 15 minutes you should be asking for help. If it's not immediately obvious or after a couple attempts at the scrapy shell then you need to ask for some help. Spending that amount of time is wasteful and makes you frustrated. This should be largely enjoyable even if you get frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to double check your `XPath`. Here's my take on it:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
html.fromstring(requests.get("https://www.karton.eu/einwellig-ab-100-mm").content).xpath("//*[@class='title']/a/text()")
```

What the code does is it takes an `html` content of the requested page, parses it to a string and applies an `XPath` selector, which searches all items of class `title`, walks down to an anchor tag `a` and extracts the text value.

The code above outputs:

`['113x113x100 mm einwellige Kartons', '140x140x100 mm einwellige Kartons', '150x100x80 mm einwellige Kartons', '150x150x150 mm einwellige Kartons', '170x150x100 mm einwellige Kartons', '190x180x100 mm einwellige Kartons']`

Comment: can you explain that code snippet a bit more to me?

Comment: well i guess i understand it now. the a stands for the subclass where the htmltag is in, right?

Comment: how do i access an html tag called small? ```<small>Artikelnummer:&nbsp;001</small>``` PS: i already got it, nvmd :)